# Как найти количество дней в месяце ? Python

Tags: python, библиотеки, импорт, календарь

Eсть импортированная библиотека

И входящие данные

```python
from calendar import monthrange
month = int(input())
```

Comment: а в чем сложность применить monthrange ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция [`monthrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange) принимает номер года и месяца, а возвращает кортеж, второй элемент которого — как раз количество дней в месяце.

Поэтому помимо самого месяца Вам также потребуется год. Получить текущий год Вы можете с помощью [`datetime.now()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now).

***Пример:***

```py
from datetime import datetime
from calendar import monthrange

current_year = datetime.now().year
month = 3  # int(input())

days = monthrange(current_year, month)[1]
print(days)
```

***stdout:***

```py
31
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Особенно за разъяснение.